# Need to use Scanner to read a file but don't know how to compare

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a method that reads a text file using Scanner then compare them to see if they are characters ('a' - 'z') however binary operators can't be used (compilation error). Any ideas how to work around it?

I need to convert uppercase letters to lowercase, and I have a counter that keep track of how many times each letter appeared in the text file.

I also need to ignore any symbols and numbers in the text file.

---

After reading your comments, I changed my code into:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterInventory {
    int counter = 0;
    private int[] inventory;

    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    public LetterInventory () {
        inventory = new int[26];
    }

    public void countOccurrences(Scanner file) {
        while (file.hasNextLine()) {
            // Read line by line and make it lowercase
            String line = file.nextLine().toLowerCase();       

            // get all the character of the line
            for (char c :line.toCharArray()) {
                if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){    // Check for character only
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayTable () {
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(alphabet[i] + ":  " + inventory[i]);
            }
        }

    public void resetInventory () {
        counter = 0;
    }
```

I am still not really sure how to make this thing work.
This program is supposed to be able to read a text file, make a count each alphabet was read, ignore any symbol/number, and output a table with each letter followed by how many times they are in the text file.

Comment: Every time you call `Scanner#next()` it tries to read the next token in the input.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know about that, what I mean is that this code won't compile because I use binary operators for string to int comparison and I don't know how to change it to work.

Comment: Show us what compilation error you get and the corresponding code.

Comment: Also, `Scanner#next()` returns a `String`. You can't compare a `String` with a `char` (directly).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the code above is the code I got compilation error from, the reason is {String} can't be compared with a {char}
How do I convert the Scanner#next() to a char? (if it's a char) and how do I ignore the Scanenr#next() if it's a symbol/number?

Comment: Look through the `String` methods.

Comment: why not just use a regular expression? for example file.next().matches("[a-z]")

Comment: @dave it is an array of alphabet 'a' - 'z'
The code is written as :
`char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();`

Comment: @Bryan how? I don't know about the `matches` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing `file.next()` to a `char` why not just use a regular expression?
For example:

```
    if(file.next().matches("[a-z]")){
      //do something
}
```

will return true if the next value picked up by the next method is a lower case character between a and z. This way you don't have to deal with unnecessary logic or worry about whether you are comparing a `String` to a `char`.

note:
I am not sure what your input is however and the above regex will only match if it is a single lower case letter not if it is a word. That said if you are reading in words you will need to split them into a character array before using the above solution.

---

For an example, you could try something like this:

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
            // grabs next word/string from file
            String str = file.next().toLowerCase();
            // converts that string to a character array
            char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

            for (char chars : charArray) {
                // converts current character into a string and checks whether
                // it
                // is a lower case letter
                if (String.valueOf(chars).matches("[a-z]")) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok, my input is a text file full of sentences. For example, it will contain something like: `My name Shy, I am 90 years old. .... etc`
How do I convert all of them into character array at once?
`file.next().toCharArray()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Read inline comments for more info.

```
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    // Read line by line and make it lowercase
    String line = file.nextLine().toLowerCase();       

    // get all the character of the line
    for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){   // check for character only
            inventory[c - 'a']++;    // Increment the occurrence of the Character
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: so this code will do:

1. if the file has nextLine, it will be converted into lowercase
2. char c is the line which was converted into a CharArray
3. `if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')` so this is if c is within 'a-z' I can do something below right?

Comment: You are going right. I have edited my post as per your code. Now there is no need of variable `counter` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments there are some problems with your code.
First: Every time you call file.next() it will try to read the next character. So what you do in your loop is: read all characters, convert to lower case but ignore this new value and carry on.

The compilation problem is due to the fact that you try to compare a string with a character.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
while(file.hasNext())
{
    String currentTokes = file.next().toLowerCase(); //save the current token as lower text in the variable
    //check each character of the string
    for(char c : currentToken.toCharArray())
    {
         if(c <= ....) //check etc.
    }

}
```

Another way would be to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
    public void countOccurrences(Scanner file) {
    int[] alpha = new int[25];
    while (file.hasNext()) {
        char[] stringTokens = file.next().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for (char c : stringTokens) {
            if (c - 'a' > -1 || c - 'a' < 26) {
                alpha[c - 'a']++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```